# INSERT result of SELECT query - LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING to handle duplicates?

Tags: postgresql

If we have a query of the kind

```
INSERT INTO target_table (......)
  SELECT (........)
  FROM origin_table
  WHERE <some conditions>
```

Let's say there could be some duplicates (for example we're selecting and inserting the id directly), so we need to handle that. What is more performant - the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL approach, or ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING?

```
INSERT INTO target_table (......)
  SELECT (........)
  FROM origin_table
  LEFT JOIN target_table ON target_table.id = origin_table.id
  WHERE <some conditions> AND target_table.id IS NULL
```

or

```
INSERT INTO target_table (......)
  SELECT (........)
  FROM origin_table
  WHERE <some conditions>
ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
```

Which one should generally be faster?

Comment: The ON CONFLICT version should be faster

Answer (score 0):

According to my benches on a table with 3 integer columns (primary keys on 2 columns) :

Those are averages.

Inserting 0 records over 6000 (i.e. 6000 conflicts) :

- `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` : 90 msec
- `LEFT JOIN` : 100 msec

Inserting 6000 records over 6000 (i.e. 0 conflicts) :

- `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` : 290 msec
- `LEFT JOIN` : 182 msec

So the conclusion of this bench is that `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` is a bit faster when they are lot of conflicts, while `LEFT JOIN` is quite faster when they are few conflicts.